# Passport.js twitter authentication causing 500 error, req.session is undefined

Tags: node.js, session, express, oauth, passport.js

I'm trying to set up sessions in a Node app using passport-twitter so I can persist user data, but from what I can tell, I cannot turn on the session support. Also, I made sure the callback function matches the application entry on Twitter Developers. The 500 error the program throws is:

```
500 Error: OAuthStrategy requires session support. Did you forget app.use(express.session(...))?**
    at Strategy.OAuthStrategy.authenticate (/Users/xxxxxxxx/web/Node/on/node_modules/passport-twitter/node_modules/passport-oauth1/lib/strategy.js:120:41)
    at Strategy.authenticate (/Users/xxxxxxxx/web/Node/on/node_modules/passport-twitter/lib/strategy.js:85:40)
    ....
```

When I check `strategy.js` at line 120, it says:

```
if (!req.session) { return this.error(new Error('OAuthStrategy requires session support. Did you forget app.use(express.session(...))?')); }
```

So, clearly req.session is undefined. However, I think I've done everything I need to to get the session support working. Here is most of my main server js file:

```
var express = require('express'),
app = express();

var http = require('http'),
https = require('https');

var mongodb = require('mongodb'),
mongoose = require('mongoose');

var passport = require('passport'),
TwitterStrategy = require('passport-twitter').Strategy,
imon = require('./imon'),
routes = require('./routes')(app),
user = require('./models/user'),
group = require('./models/group'),
song = require('./models/song'),
album = require('./models/album'),
activity_item = require('./models/activity_item');

app.set('env', 'development');

console.log("app.get('env') =", app.get('env'));
console.log(app.get('env') === 'development');

// development only
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
    app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
    app.use(express.logger('dev'));
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
    app.use(express.methodOverride());
    app.use(express.cookieParser('secret'));
    app.use(express.cookieSession());
    app.use(passport.initialize());
    app.use(passport.session());
    app.use(app.router);
    app.use(express.errorHandler());
}

// production only
if (app.get('env') === 'production') {
  // TODO
}


// all environments


mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');
var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', function callback () {
  console.log('Connected to DB');
});


passport.use(new TwitterStrategy({
    consumerKey: "0GOReNaXWXCTpf7OQgrg",
    consumerSecret: "0wA8yUBrXz3ivpTHcuBbKp3vGN2ODnOF7iFM9DB48Y",
    callbackURL: "http://127.0.0.1:8888/auth/twitter/callback"
  },
    function(token, tokenSecret, profile, done) {
        console.log("THis gets called?");
        function sanitizeImgURL(string){
            return string.replace("_normal", "");
        }

        console.log("profile: ", profile);
        process.nextTick(function(){
            User.find({account: {id: profile.id}}, function(err, user) {
                if(err){
                    return done(err);
                }
                if(!user){
                    return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect password.' });
                }
                else if(user){
                    done(null, user);
            }
            var newUser = new User(
                {account:
                    {provider: profile.provider,
                    id: profile.id},
                username: profile.username,
                displayName: profile.displayName,
                email: profile.email,
                image: sanitizeImgURL(profile._json.profile_image_url)
            });
            return done(null, newUser);
        });
    });
    }
));

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    console.log("SERIALIZE: ", user);
  done(null, user);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(obj, done) {
    console.log("DESERIALIZE: ", obj);
  done(null, obj);
});


/**
 * Routes
 */

// Redirect the user to Twitter for authentication.  When complete, Twitter
// will redirect the user back to the application at
//   /auth/twitter/callback
app.get('/auth/twitter', passport.authenticate('twitter'));

// Twitter will redirect the user to this URL after approval.  Finish the
// authentication process by attempting to obtain an access token.  If
// access was granted, the user will be logged in.  Otherwise,
// authentication has failed.
app.get('/auth/twitter/callback',
  passport.authenticate('twitter', { successRedirect: '/static/index.html',
                                     failureRedirect: '/static/login.html' }));
```

... some routes ...

```
app.listen(8888);
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out; it was 2 things:

1.)`connect-redis` broke sessions, still don't know why, but removing it fixed my problem after I...

2.)... moved my require routes line, which takes the `app` object as an argument to after my `app.use` statements.  It makes sense now, I was passing my `app` object to my `routes` before I configured it with things like, i dunno, SESSIONS.